# How can I play different sound files on click?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, event-listener

I built a simple matching game and added audio files for several cards like this:

```
cardList.map((cardItem) => {
var card = document.createElement("li");
card.classList.add("card");

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = [cardItem.img]


  card.appendChild(img);

//audio starting here

audio = new Audio(cardItem.sound);
card.appendChild(audio);

audio.id += ' ' + cardItem.card;

deck.append(card);

card.className += ' ' + cardItem.name;
});
}
```

And in my startGame() function I added an eventListener to add audio.play(); on click.

So now, when I open dev tools, I can see audio elements for my cards but when I try and click on them, I'm only ever getting one audio file for all cards and not the audios I actually added to that specific element.

That's my GitHub file: https://github.com/cMikolai/guitar-colour-system-game/blob/master/js/app.js

Could anybody try and help me figure out how I could play the sound I added to the card I am clicking on?

Comment: I have found the cause behind the problem. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your code and played around. The code for playing audio is in the function `startGame()` in your **app.js** file.

**app.js:**

```
audio = []; // local variable declaration

...
... 

// some code

function startGame() {

  // some code

  for (var i = 0; i < clickedCard.length; i++) {
    clickedCard[i].addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    this.classList.add("open", "show");

    openCards.push(this.getAttribute("class"));

    audio.load();
    audio.play(); // this is the line playing the audio

    matchCards();
    starRating();

    }, false);
  }
}
```

As you can see, you are not playing audio from the selected card but from the local variable `audio`.

So, you have to identify the selected card and play its respective audio instead of playing audio from the local variable.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I've been completely blind, solved now :)